# Force PHP newline to respect current indentation level

Tags: php, html-table, newline

I have been googling like crazy to find an answer to what I thought would have been a very common question to no avail...

I am using "\n" to break a table into a more readable structure when viewing source. Is there any way to get it to respect current indentation levels? For example:

Turn this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Data</td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>Data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Into this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am printing the `tbody` rows and cells out with the following code:

```
<?php
    $first = true;
    foreach ($data->rows as $row) {
        if ($first) {
            print "<tr class='highlight'>";
            $first = false;
        } else {
            print "<tr>";
        }
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            print "<td>";
            printf('%s', $cell);
            print  "</td>\n";
        }
        print "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: A newline is just a newline. If you want to add indentation, you need to do it yourself. Multiply the current nesting level by 2 and print that many spaces.

Comment: You're probably looking for `\t`

Comment: @Barmar - Hmm, good idea! But I can see that being quite cumbersome. How would it work if you were to have files that are included at different indentation levels throughout an application / document?

Comment: You could just use the browser's web inspector if you just want to see the code indented..

Comment: @Ben - Ah i was not aware of \t, but it only adds a tab to the end of the current line. To get this to work i would need to add \n\t\t to get the desired effect on some line which feels a little too  neckbeard for my liking. Maybe i am just being too anal. I know that i can use the inspector to view the code but sometimes use the source view to look for any errors that inspectors sometimes clean up.

Comment: I didn't intend it as a general solution for the whole document, just when you're formatting something like a table or nested lists.

Comment: HTML code needs to be machine readable, not necessarily human readable. If you need to look at it "manually", there are many ways to *beautify* it later. I wouldn't spend a single line of source code doing so.

Comment: Very vaild points all. Thanks for the advice. I think the general consensuses is that it can be done, but could potentially be quite wasteful and not necessarily worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $first = true;
    foreach ($data->rows as $row) {
        if ($first) {
            echo "\t\t<tr class='highlight'>";
            $first = false;
        } else {
            print "\t\t<tr>";
        }
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            print "\t\t\t<td>";
            printf("\t\t\t\t%s", $cell);
            print  "</td>\n";
        }
        print "\t\t</tr>\n";
    }
?>
```

I recommend you to write an identation counter, if you would like to do it dynamically. And remember to use double quotes for escape sequences, single quotes won´t work here (because it´s treated like a variable).

Answer (score 0):

This is what google gave me.

You should concatinate the entire table in one php string, parse it through the function that can be found here:

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2007/04/05/format-xml-with-php/

and then simply echo $xml;

I just found it, I give no guarantee that this works as itended but it looks reliable.

Comment: Great find! I am knocking off work at the moment but will check this out tomorrow and get back to you with an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The final HTML source have not to respect an indentation... Nobody see it (or you but don't get crazy with this).

Ok, sometimes this is also an obsession for me (one among many others ?), so you can do:

```
echo '
    <tr>';
//Loop starts
    echo '
        <td></td>';
// Loop ends
echo '
    </tr>';
```

Here you get a newline and your HTML indentation is independant from the PHP one.
Is it what you would ?

Comment: he wants it to be formatted nicely for himself when viewing source.